# Почему так долго выполняется код циклов на Python по сравнению с Java или C

Tags: python, c

Почему так долго выполняется код циклов на Python по сравнению с Java или C

```
counter = 0
q = pow(2, 16) - 1
m = pow(2,20)
z = 7 * 16 ** 3 + 12 * 16 ** 2

for cs in range(q + 1):
    for addr in range(q + 1):
        if (cs*16 + addr) % m == z:
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Сравните по скорости с аналогичным на Си

```
int main(){
  int counter = 0;
  int q = (int) pow(2, 16)-1;
  int m = (int) pow(2,20);
  int cs;
  for (cs = 0; cs <= q ; cs++) {
    int addr;
    for (addr = 0; addr <= q ; addr++) {
      if ((cs * 16 + addr) % m == 0x7c00){
        counter++;           
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n",counter);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, они не аналогичны. Чтобы были аналогичны в вашем Сишном коде должны использоваться итераторы, все данные должны быть объектами, размещёнными в куче, а все операции вызовами методов этих объектов. Во-вторых, в CPython тело цикла будет интерпретироваться на каждой итерации, что очевидно медленнее выполнения машинного кода.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Почему так долго выполняется цикл отвечать не буду, так как вам уже ответили. К тому же, подозреваю, что это волнует вас меньше, чем ответ на вопрос "Как это исправить?"...

Используйте **Numba**:

```
from numba import jit


@jit
def test():
    counter = 0
    q = pow(2, 16) - 1
    m = pow(2, 20)
    z = 7 * 16 ** 3 + 12 * 16 ** 2

    for cs in range(q + 1):
        for addr in range(q + 1):
            if (cs * 16 + addr) % m == z:
                counter += 1
```

Мой результат скорости выполнения - 0.30512189865112305 секунды!

> Библиотека [**Numba**](http://numba.pydata.org/) предоставляет возможность **jit** (*just-in-time*) компиляции кода на питоне в байт-код сравнимый по производительности с **Cи** или **Fortran** кодом. **Numba** поддерживает компиляцию и запуск python-кода не только на **CPU**, но и на **GPU**, при этом стиль и вид программы, использующей библиотеку **Numba**, остается чисто питоновским.

Answer (score 2):

Причины медлительности Python (он медленный не только в циклах а вообще в целом):

1. GIL (Global Interpreter Lock, глобальная блокировка интерпретатора), но это не относится к данному примеру
2. Python — это интерпретируемый, а не компилируемый язык (на каждой итерации приходится интерпретировать снова все операторы)
3. Динамическая типизация (тратится время на проверку типов)

   Подробнее [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/418823/) и [тут](https://proglib.io/p/why-is-python-so-slow/).

Comment: GIL в данном примере вообще не при чём. Более того, без него этот код мог бы быть ещё и медленнее.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Речь не о данном примере а о Python в принципе. Тем не мене, поправлю.

Answer (score 1):

Python в отличие от C и даже Java интерпретируемый язык, а не компилируемый. Добавьте сюда динамическую типизацию, которая также скорости не добавляет. Вот и получается снижение скорости выполнения.

Конечно, всё это справедливо при прочих равных условиях.

Очень многое ещё зависит от самой реализации алгоритма. Можно и на ассемблере так написать цикл, что он будет работать медленнее чем другой алгоритм решающий аналогичную задачу на том же Python.

Comment: С Java, в частности с HotSpot, всё несколько сложнее - у неё есть JIT. Кроме того, для данного примера она оперировала бы примитивами в стеке. После прогрева этот код вряд ли будет медленнее Сишного, а в некоторых случаях может оказаться даже быстрее.