# Почему С++ быстрее многих языков программирования?

Tags: c++

Достаточно интересно полностью понять, почему С++ настолько быстр по сравнению с условным Kotlin, Java или C#.

**Вопрос:** *Расскажите пожалуйста в деталях, почему именно так) Предполагаю, что это благодаря достаточно гибкой работой с памятью, но кажется, что сильно заблуждаюсь)*

Comment: Потому что он компилируется в машинный код, который выполняется процессором напрямую, а не через виртуальную машину какую-нибудь

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему так долго выполняется код циклов на Python по сравнению с Java или C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017267/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%81-java-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-c)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin тут вопрос не про Python

Comment: @andreymal, какая разница? ответы там есть и они полностью покрывают смысл данного вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin целых три принципиальных разницы: в питоне (подразумеваю CPython) есть GIL, нет статической типизации и нет JIT-компиляации — а в Java и C# всё ровно наоборот

Comment: С++ (в основном) следует принципу «не платишь за то, что не используешь».

Comment: компиляция тут не причем (в других нормальных языках компиляция осуществляется при запуске). за скорость отвечает оптимизатор. да с++ быстр но не на много.

Comment: С набиолее близок к реальному устройству CPU. C является подмножеством C++. С++ **компилируется** в машинный код, а всякие Java и C# в **байт-код виртуальной машины**. С JS, Python и т.п. дела ещё хуже, они **интерпретируемые**, хотя тоже могут в байт-код "компилироваться".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во, я наверное хорошо смогу ответить, так как являюсь специалистом в C# и .NET

Но перед тем как вникать в суть, запомните основное правило: **тормозит не язык, на котором вы написали код или среда выполнения, тормозит сам код, который вы написали.**

И главная проблема плохого тормозящего кода в таких средах со сборщиком мусора, как .NET и Java, это отсутствие экспертизы в области поведения той самой машины управления памятью. Хочешь создать 200кк массивов для выполнения задачи - легко, код прост. Просто спавни объекты и ни о чем не думай, а сборщик мусора разберется.

В таких средах, где нет встроенного управления памятью, и надо его писать по большей части самому, приходится разбираться с этим до того как код дописать, потому что иначе будут утечки и прочие неприятности. Когда учишь С++, изначально познаешь базовые тонкости работы с памятью, а многие новички сразу начинают различать `malloc` и `calloc`, и осознавать, что выделение высвобождение памяти не бесплатно по времени и требует работы, переиспользуют память и т.д.

Чтобы научиться контролю аллокаций в средах типа .NET, требуется сначала написать много тормознутого кода, и наконец-то встретиться с проблемой низкой производительности или перерасхода памяти лицом к лицу. То есть вникание в управление памятью и суть работы сборщика происходит гораздо позднее. Поэтому при одинаковом объеме обучающих материалов, специалист по C++ узнает про нюансы производительности раньше, чем специалист по C#. И это нормально, это специфика среды, в которой работает код.

Поэтому вопрос *"что быстрее, С++ или C#/Java"* изначально не имеет смысла. Даже если столкнуть лбами двух супермегаэкспертов C++ и C# - неизвестно, чей код будет быстрее. Напишешь на C++ код, потом начнешь тестировать, на одном сервере победишь C#, на другом в другой архитектуре - проиграешь. Ну потому что JIT во время компиляции знает все тонкости процессора, выполняющего код, а компилятор C++ - не знает, он знает только архитектуру. Есть еще PGO (Profile-Guided Optimization) в CLR (Common Language Runtime/.NET) - великолепная шутка, которая может перекомпилировать с сильными оптимизациями код уже запущенного приложения в зависимости от интенсивности использования некоторых методов в коде (речь про последние версии .NET, но раньше ситуация была хуже). В C++ такого либо нет, либо оно достигается значительно тяжелее, чем в среде с JIT. И еще миллионы нюансов, которые никак не ответят на ваш вопрос однозначно.

И здесь можно повторить вывод, который написан жирным шрифтом выше, в самом начале. А утверждение *"С++ быстрее многих языков программирования"* по факту не соответствует действительности. Я могу на C# написать код, который будет например применять фильтр к Full HD картинке 2 секунды, а могу потом переписать его так, что станет потом 4мс, а качество машинного кода, который выдает JIT, будет не сильно хуже, чем генерит gcc/clang. Не забывайте, что компиляция байт-кода (или CIL) производится машиной в целом однократно, а затем уже работает только скомпилированная версия. Например вызываете какой-то метод 1000 раз, а компилироваться он будет только однажды. JIT - это не интерпритатор байт-кода, а компилятор.

Answer (score 2):

Большинство языков работают не напрямую. К примеру Java использует JVM, у C# это CLR, а Python с помощью CPython (стандартная реализация) компилируется в байт-код, который затем обрабатывается в "ручную".  Это все даёт различные плюсы, но тратит ресурсы. В С/С++ этот этап отсутствует, он на прямую компилируется в машинный код.

Также он даёт возможность работать с памятью на прямую. Это не всегда безопасно, но также влияет на скорость работы.

Comment: хочу отметить, что в [C# код компилится в машинный при запуске](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620348/how-and-when-does-ngen-exe-work), а своя реализация работы с памятью будет медленнее стандартной (в каждой версии .NET ее оптимизируют, над этим работает куча программистов).

Answer (score -2):

Это не C++ быстрый, а C быстрый, т.к. проектировался как замена макроассемблеру, с учётом особенностей железа. Пока Вы используете C-подмножество языка C++ - он быстрый, а стоит просто включить в текст стандартные C++ заголовки, как врубается поддержка C++ исключений и всё начинает тормозить.

Comment: На первый взгляд звучит как чушь, я везде читал, что исключения тормозят только когда они используются (то есть выполняется throw). Или у вас есть достоверные бенчмарки, показывающие, что C++ код становится медленнее даже без выбрасывания исключений?

Comment: @andreymal https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220228-00/?p=106296 Другое дело, что исключения не медленнее, чем эквивалентная обработка ошибок, вручную написанная на С. И да, поддержка исключений врубается в С++ и без включения каких-либо заголовков. Так что в ответе написана чепуха.

Comment: Возьмите код без исключений и без включения стандартных C++ заголовков и откомпилируйте его с поддержкой исключений и без, посмотрите ассемблерный листинг - они различаются в прологе и эпилоге функциии.

Comment: @Ddd пофиг на ассемблерный листинг, на практике-то измеримая разница в производительности есть? Вы бенчмарки проводили?

Comment: Впрочем, это всё равно бессмысленная флудильня, так как ответ не имеет отношения к вопросу, который просит сравнить C#/Java и C++, а не C++ и C

Comment: Измеримая разница есть, в моём случае она составила ~15%, наверное можно подобрать и больше. Программа должна отвечать следующим условиям: а) быть занятой вычислениями, а не ожиданием диска, сети, пользователя и т.д.; б) вычисления должны быть распределены по нескольким функциям, которые интенсивно вызывают друг-друга или вызываются третьей функцией; в) откомпилирована cl или icl, у gcc исключения всегда включены, судя по-всему; Сильно меня это удивило: вписываешь строчку "#include <algorithm>" - получаешь замедление, закомментируешь - всё восстанавливается.

Comment: Это не `C` быстрый, а `C++` потому что `C++` при компиляции алгоритмов учитывает типы данных и встраивает функции, а в `C` даже для простой сортировки требуется делать неустранимые вызовы к функции-компаратору.

Comment: `вписываешь строчку "#include <algorithm>" - получаешь замедление, закомментируешь - всё восстанавливается.` Можно конкретный пример кода?

Comment: @wololo
 Ещё бы знать как тут код вводить... ```#if 1
template <class T>
inline T clamp(const T& X,const T& LoX,const T& HiX) { return (X < LoX)?(LoX):((HiX < X)?(HiX):(X)); }
#else
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
#endif

int CallClamp(int x,int lo,int hi) { return clamp(x,lo,hi); }
``` Командная строка: icl /c /FA -std=c++17 "!proba1.cpp" . 1 - 7 ассемблерных команд, 0 - 12 ассемблерных команд.

Comment: 1) `Ещё бы знать как тут код вводить.` [Справка по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). 2) В вашем примере кода при включении `<algorithm>` компилируется не ваша функция `clamp`, а стандартная `std::clamp`. И хотя такая замена в данном конкретном случае не повлияет на наблюдаемое поведение функции `CallClamp`, нет ничего удивительного, что разные функции (как минимум, стандартная `std::clamp` возвращает ссылку) транслируются в отличающийся ассемблерный код. Пока не понятно, как включение стандартных заголовочных файлов или исключений должно замедлить вашу функцию `clamp`.

Comment: 3) `1 - 7 ассемблерных команд, 0 - 12 ассемблерных команд.` Ну, gcc транслирует обе версии функции `CallClamp` в [шесть ассемблерных команд](https://godbolt.org/z/Yvxnn7qhW).